# Joomla 1.5 with Virtuemart 1.1.9

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla1.5, virtuemart

I want add changing on category page, I customize page `websitelink.com/components\com_virtuemart\themes\default\templates\browse\browse_3.php`

I add code

```
    <div class="addtocart_buttonList">
<?php 
$button_lbl = $VM_LANG->_('PHPSHOP_CART_ADD_TO');
$button_cls = 'addtocart_button';
if( CHECK_STOCK == '1' && ( $product_in_stock < 1 ) ) {
    $button_lbl = $VM_LANG->_('VM_CART_NOTIFY');
    $button_cls = 'notify_button';
    $notify = true;
} else {
    $notify = false;
}
?>

<form action="<?php echo $mm_action_url ?>index.php" method="post" name="addtocart" id="addtocart<?php echo $i ?>" class="addtocart_form" <?php if( $this->get_cfg( 'useAjaxCartActions', 1 ) && !$notify ) { echo 'onsubmit="handleAddToCart( this.id );return false;"'; } ?>>

    <input type="submit" class="<?php echo $button_cls ?>" value="<?php echo $button_lbl    ?>" title="<?php echo $button_lbl ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="<?php echo  @$_REQUEST['category_id'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo $product_id ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="prod_id[]" value="<?php echo $product_id ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="shop.cart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="func" value="cartadd" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Itemid" value="<?php echo $sess->getShopItemid() ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_virtuemart" />
    <input type="hidden" name="set_price[]" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="adjust_price[]" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="master_product[]" value="" />
</form>
</div>
```

After adding this line add to cart button appear on list items, but than i click on add to cart button error will come

```
Please enter a valid quatity for this item
```

How i can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a quantity as an input field, hidden  or otherwise.  We only wanted the customer to be able to order one of an item, so added this code:

```
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="quantity">
```

Having that named input field satisifed the Virtuemart validation.